# How to get access field property in visual basic 2017

Tags: ms-access

For my program I want to use accdb database, created with Access 2016. Now I want to set the textboxes and such so that it will have the same length and property (short text, long text, number or so) as the datafield has.

Is there a way to get this kind of info in visual basic 2017? the table and row name are both known.

I have search the internet, but can't find any information about this. The only thing I saw was schema info, but this I don't understand exactly.

Thanks,
Hans

Answer (score 0):

Query the [Type property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/field-type-property-dao) of the Field object, e.g.:

```vb
CurrentDb.TableDefs("YourTable").Fields("YourField").Type
```

This will return one of the following enumerations:

```
+-------------------+--------------------------+
| Constant          |       Description        |
+-------------------+--------------------------+
| 16 | dbBigInt     | Big Integer              |
|  9 | dbBinary     | Binary                   |
|  1 | dbBoolean    | Boolean                  |
|  2 | dbByte       | Byte                     |
| 18 | dbChar       | Char                     |
|  5 | dbCurrency   | Currency                 |
|  8 | dbDate       | Date/Time                |
| 20 | dbDecimal    | Decimal                  |
|  7 | dbDouble     | Double                   |
| 21 | dbFloat      | Float                    |
| 15 | dbGUID       | GUID                     |
|  3 | dbInteger    | Integer                  |
|  4 | dbLong       | Long                     |
| 11 | dbLongBinary | Long Binary (OLE Object) |
| 12 | dbMemo       | Memo                     |
| 19 | dbNumeric    | Numeric                  |
|  6 | dbSingle     | Single                   |
| 10 | dbText       | Text                     |
| 22 | dbTime       | Time                     |
| 23 | dbTimeStamp  | Time Stamp               |
| 17 | dbVarBinary  | VarBinary                |
+----+--------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Hello Lee, I'm sorry, but this seems an VBA command. can I also use this in Visual Basic 2017 and if so, can you also tell me how?